# MYSQL improve performance in a very big table

Tags: mysql

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE llegada (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `emc_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `cuartel_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `nro_entrada` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `valor` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ind_llegada` (`emc_id`,`cuartel_id`,`fecha`,`nro_entrada`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=18822145 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

This tablet has approximately 100000000 records. And to improve the performance I would like to partition to this table, in 6 parts depending on the year. But first two problems happens I'm not sure how to do it and not know if would modify the queries made to the table. My idea would not have to modify the query page that accesses the database.
Thanks for advance.

Comment: It is not clear what is your question. Which queries suffer from bad performance? Why do you think partitioning will help?

Comment: Did you use `EXPLAIN` on your queries?

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of a way to partition sql itself without just creating multiple databases. As you said, you'll need to modify the query page or the way information is stored to the various databases on your site, which you should do anyway because that's going to be a lot of wasted processing time. I'm surprised it hasn't already affected your user experience.